# Script to index documents with a special name

Tags: batch-file, solr

I'm currently use this line to send a document to Solr :

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/core/update/extractliteral.id=doc1&commit=true" -F myfile=@C:\path\doc1.txt
```

I want to write a script to browse all folders and only extract document begin with XX_ or X_ and with any extension except `.html` but I don't know how to do this

Comment: You have used two conflicting tags.  `SHELL` is usually for Unix and Linux based systems and `BATCH-FILE` is for Windows based systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this `.bat` at the root where you want to start the search.

```
@echo off
Echo Searching !!

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b /s') do (
   if not "%%~xa"==".html" (
      set "$file=%%~nxa"
      set "$file=!$file:XX_=X_!"
      if "!$file:~0,2!"=="X_" echo File found : %%a
   )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, how can i do to have all files except ones with and `.html` extension ?

Comment: Check my Edit !!